# How do I post more than one parameter using spring @requestparam/@requestbody annotation in json format

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data

I want to upload an item object with it's image is it possible that   i pass a complete object of my Item along with it's image from my Controller if yes then how may i Do it? and I need a Json Pattern also which will be coming from client side.

What would be the Json pattern for my following Item Object.

```
Class Item{

String ItemID;
String ItemName;
String CategoryID;
List<Image> imagesList;

}

Class Image{

String imageId;
String imageTitle;
byte[] image;
}
```

and one more thing. Please tell me how can I pass two parameters in my Controller. e.g. if I want to pass Item object in the Request Body along with an extra parameter say String UserID. HOw may I write the following code.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public void add(@RequestBody Item myItem, String UserID) 

{ ...... }
```

and please tell me what if I pass in the Request in  Json format. What will be it looks like?

```
{ "Item" : { "ItemID": "1", ......}, "UserID" : "hello"}
```

will it be like this or what? because i tried it i'm getting the Object and string as Null. I also tried it with @RequestParam but same got NULL while debugging.

Currently i'm dealing with this by this.

```
Class ItemUserPost{
    Item item;
    String UserID;
}
```

I'm storing this object in MongoDB. Will be my whole collection of Item will stored along with the images? or i have to use a MultiPart and GridFS API for this. Kindly please refer if related question already posted.

Please Help Urgent.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please any one can help me it's urgent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Request Body it's just ONE body. You cannot pass multiple objects or parameters in the same body.

There is 2 turnovers for this:

1. If you're using REST, you can put the UserID on `@RequestMapping(value = "{userId}")` and get it from the URL. Or, you can simply put the UserId as query parameter on your url.
2. Keep using your `ItemUserPost` object.

--

And for the second question:

Yes, It will store your collection with the images.

Comment: I need one more help regarding uploading an image from iOS to my Resource getting the @RequestParam as CommonsMultipart fileUpload. Every thing is working fine from my client iOS but i'm getting 404 Not Found response. I found out that it's not hitting my Resource on API service. Please let me know if you want to see the code for more clarification. 

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This is my Resource Function:

`@RequestMapping(value = "/storeimages", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public void storeItemImages(@RequestParam  CommonsMultipartFile[] fileUpload) throws Exception {

// Working of input stream & storing it in DB

}`

Comment: Your web.xml have the mapped Spring servlet at `/` only? Or your put another context. The most of these problems are the incorrectly mapping in web.xml Spring's servlet. What is the context of you project and your full context to this resource? Sorry for answer only today.